# NodeJS, Axios - post file from local server to another server

Tags: node.js, axios, multipartform-data

I have an API endpoint that lets the client post their csv to our server then post it to someone else server. I have done our server part which save uploaded file to our server, but I can't get the other part done. I keep getting error `{ message: 'File not found', code: 400 }` which may mean the file never reach the server. I'm using axios as an agent, does anyone know how to get this done? Thanks.

```
// file = uploaded file
const form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append("file", fs.createReadStream(file.path));
const request_config = {
    method: "post",
    url: url,
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token,
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    },
    data: form_data
};
return axios(request_config);
```

**Update**

As axios doc states as below and the API I'm trying to call requires a file

> // `data` is the data to be sent as the request body
>         // Only applicable for request methods 'PUT', 'POST', and 'PATCH'
>         // When no `transformRequest` is set, must be of one of the following types:
>         // - string, plain object, ArrayBuffer, ArrayBufferView, URLSearchParams
>         // - Browser only: FormData, File, Blob
>         // - Node only: Stream, Buffer

Is there any way to make axios send a file as a whole? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#using-multipartform-data-format

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm thinking the createReadStream is your issue because its async. try this.
Since createReadStream extends the event emitter, we can "listen" for when it finishes/ends.

```
var newFile = fs.createReadStream(file.path);

// personally I'd function out the inner body here and just call 
// to the function and pass in the newFile
newFile.on('end', function() {
  const form_data = new FormData();
  form_data.append("file", newFile, "filename.ext");
  const request_config = {
    method: "post",
    url: url,
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token,
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    },
    data: form_data
  };
  return axios(request_config);
});
```

Comment: Hi James. Your solution does work. However, does `createReadStream` read the entire file into memory, if yes, I might encounter memory problem for massive files.

Comment: So, with the Request module (import it), you could do that easily like so:
newFile.pipe(request(request_config)) . I think axios might be able to do it too. But the the idea is, stream in the file, and pipe it to the request/axios to transfer.

Comment: @jamesemanon have you any code snippet to pipe the file stream for axios upload? if so, please post here

Comment: How to do it in case one wants to upload multiple files ? @jamesemanon

Comment: what's the solution if we have used multer

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer! In typescript I get an error: `Argument of type 'ReadStream' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'.
  Type 'ReadStream' is missing the following properties from type 'Blob': size, type, arrayBuffer, slice, and 2 more.`

Any ideas?

Comment: For typescript add `import FormData from "form-data";`

Answer (score 72):

The 2 oldest answers did not work for me. This, however, did the trick:

```
const FormData = require('form-data'); // npm install --save form-data

const form = new FormData();
form.append('file', fs.createReadStream(file.path));

const request_config = {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${access_token}`,
    ...form.getHeaders()
  }
};

return axios.post(url, form, request_config);
```

`form.getHeaders()` returns an Object with the content-type as well as the boundary.
For example:

```
{ "content-type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=-------------------0123456789" }
```

Comment: This was very helpful. Thanks a lot!
Here is another useful example showing how to mimic file upload without using a filesystem: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1006#issuecomment-320165427.

Comment: Works like a charm. This is very helpful. Non of above solutions worked.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer! In typescript I get an error: Argument of type 'ReadStream' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'.   Type 'ReadStream' is missing the following properties from type 'Blob': size, type, arrayBuffer, slice, and 2 more. Any ideas?

Comment: What if I have a file buffer instead of a file path?

Comment: @GabrielAugusto use `import FormData from "form-data";`

Comment: this answer helped in in 2023

Comment: Instead of a file from the filesystem, I wanted to send the multer uploaded file right away. What worked for me was to convert my buffer into a Blob like this: `form.append("file", new Blob([file.buffer], { type: file.mimetype }));`.
Took me a while to figure this one out, hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 10):

This is what you really need:

```
const form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append("file", fs.createReadStream(file.path));

const request_config = {
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token,
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
  },
  data: form_data
};

return axios
  .post(url, form_data, request_config);
```

Comment: It seems there is a little mistake in your sample: you miss the filename... The right code is ` form_data.append("file", fs.createReadStream(file.path), "filename.ext");

Answer (score 8):

In my case, fs.createReadStream(file.path) did not work.
I had to use buffer instead.

```
const form = new FormData();
form.append('file', fs.readFileSync(filePath), fileName);

const config = {
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${auth.access_token}`,
    ...form.getHeaders(),
  },
};

axios.post(api, form.getBuffer(), config);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made an interceptor you can connect to axios to handle this case in node: [`axios-form-data`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-form-data). Any feedback would be welcome.

- `npm i axios-form-data`
- example:

```js
import axiosFormData from 'axios-form-data';
import axios from 'axios';

// connect axiosFormData interceptor to axios
axios.interceptors.request.use(axiosFormData);

// send request with a file in it, it automatically becomes form-data
const response = await axios.request({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://httpbin.org/post',
  data: {
    nonfile: 'Non-file value',
    // if there is at least one streamable value, the interceptor wraps the data into FormData
    file: createReadStream('somefile'),
  },
});

// response should show "files" with file content, "form" with other values
// and multipart/form-data with random boundary as request header
console.log(response.data);
```

Answer (score 1):

**For anyone who wants to upload files from their local filesystem (actually from anywhere with the right streams architecture) with `axios` and doesn't want to use any external packages (like form-data).**

Just create a readable stream and plug it right into `axios` request function like so:

```
await axios.put(
  url,
  fs.createReadStream(path_to_file)
)
```

Axios accepts data argument of type Stream in node context.

Works fine for me at least in Node `v.16.13.1` and with axios `v.0.27.2`

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue, I had a "pdf-creator-service" for generate PDF document from html.

I use mustache template engine for create HTML document - https://www.npmjs.com/package/mustache
`Mustache.render` function returns html as a string what do I need to do to pass it to the `pdf-generator-service` ? So lets see my suggestion bellow

```
//...

async function getPdfDoc(props: {foo: string, bar: string}): Promise<Buffer> {
    const temlateFile = readFileSync(joinPath(process.cwd(), 'file.html'))

    mustache.render(temlateFile, props)
    const readableStream = this.getReadableStreamFromString(htmlString)

    const formData = new FormData() // from 'form-data'
    formData.append('file', options.file, { filename: options.fileName })
    const formHeaders = formData.getHeaders()

    return await axios.send<Buffer>(
      {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://pdf-generator-service-url/pdf',
        data: formData,
        headers: {
          ...formHeaders,
        },
        responseType: 'arraybuffer', // ! important
      },
    )

}

getReadableStreamFromString(str: string): Readable {
    const bufferHtmlString = Buffer.from(str)
    const readableStream = new Readable() // from 'stream'

    readableStream._read = () => null // workaround error
    readableStream.push(bufferHtmlString)
    readableStream.push(null) // mark end of stream

    return readableStream
}
```