# Why am I getting Invalid Form data error on slack web api?

Tags: javascript, electron, slack-api

I'm trying to upload a file to slack but constantly getting an error saying `invalid_form_data`. I'm building an electronJS app and using the following code to upload the file:

```
const filee = fs.createReadStream(file);
  (async () => {

    const result = await web.files.upload({
      channels: '#general',
      file: filee
    })

  })()
```

I have even tried to post using axios but ran into the same problem. The code is:

```
const upload_url = 'https://slack.com/api/files.upload'
  let file = null
  fs.readFile(file_path, 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
    file = data
  });
  const post = {
    channels: "#general",
    file: file
  }

  axios.post(upload_url, post, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  }).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response['data']['ok'])
  }).then(function (err) {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

I have also tried formData module, like so:

```
const upload_url = 'https://slack.com/api/files.upload'
  const formData = new FormData();
  let file = null
  fs.readFile(file_path, function (err, data) {
    file = data
  });

  formData.append("file", file);
  axios.post(upload_url, formData, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  }).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response['data']['error'])
  }).then(function (err) {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may want to use the [`form-data`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) module for this. Example usage with Axios [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55745576/1913729).

Comment: @blex As a matter of fact, I did try that as well. It throws an error `Data after transformation must be a string, an ArrayBuffer, a Buffer, or a Stream`. I have updated my question with the code.

Comment: I just tried your first snippet (using the [`slack` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slack)) and it worked the first time for me... Weird. I just created a bot, added the `files:write` scope to it, installed the bot in my workspace to get the token, and used [this code](https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/062NMxdK).

Comment: which package did you use? I'm using @slack/web-api

Comment: I used the one I linked above (just [`slack`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slack)) . I'll give it a try with just `files:write:user` scope

Comment: Also, I don't have a `files:write` scope in my app. I only have `files:write:user`

Comment: alright, let me know. In the mean time, I'll try the package you mentioned.

Comment: @blex well, I used the package you mentioned and it worked. No idea what was wrong with the other package since that's office as well. Thanks though

Comment: Cool :+1: Also worked for me using `files:write:user`