# try to send image in json from my nestjs api to another api

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, httpservice

I'm trying to send json with image to another api from my nesjs api,
I'm using httpservice.post but always getting an error - "no file supplied".

the image is ulpoaded from the user and saved in the public folder,
then I try to get the image from the folder and send it to the api.

in the remote api they expect - raw data image and Content-Type: multipart/form-data in the header,
I tried both but it doesn't work.

this is the code:

```
const image = await fs.createReadStream(`./public/storage/images/${image.filename}`);

let imageData = {
            "file": image,
            "caption": tag,
            "isLogo": false
}

const res = await this.httpService.post(
                    `${urlapi}`,
                   imageData,
                    {   
                        headers: {
                            "Authorization": `Bearer ${access_token}`,
                            "Content-Type": "application/json"
                        }   
                    }
                )
                .toPromise();
```

I'm new at nestjs and node, I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: You can read the image that you want to send as a raw and send it via your API

Comment: how do i do that? everything i tried doesn't work.

Comment: Does the image in question exist at `<projectRoot>/dist/public/storage/images/${image.filename}`? If not, that would explain why there's no file there.

Comment: yes, i was able to copy it to another folder, i think my problem is with sending the image in the httpservie. i also tried to use axios but it doesn't work.

Comment: NestJS is using axios, so you can google for that to get more results. I think this could solve your task: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53040878/6533425 - Basically you need a new FormData object and attach the image read stream to it. That you pass to axios.

Comment: i tried it with form data and axios, still the same error - "no file supplied" :(