# Uploading file via Axios config

Tags: node.js

I want to change my axios setup to upload multiple files within it

I am trying to pass it to data if the `req.file` exist
But it does not work
Is there any way to access request file by `req.file`
What if it is defined in backend?

(Like code below)

```
 axios({
    url: URL + req.url,
    method: req.method,
     ...(
        (!req.file)
        ? { data: req.body }
        : { data: req.file }
    ),
})
```

Comment: Neither. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53038900/nodejs-axios-post-file-from-local-server-to-another-server for an example of how to do it properly.

Answer (score -1):

Add the file to a formData object, and set the Content-Type header to multipart/form-data.

```
var formData = new FormData();
var imagefile = document.querySelector('#file');
formData.append("image", imagefile.files[0]);
axios.post('upload_file', formData, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
})
```

Reference [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43013858/how-to-post-a-file-from-a-form-with-axios)