# Telegram Bot - How to upload local files with absolute/ dynamic URL

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, chatbot

I'm trying to send photos through telegram bot using 'sendPhoto' method with relative url (Image at file level). I'm not using any library, here is my call function:

```
let axiosImage = async (chatId, caption, res) => {
try {
    await axios.post(`${TELEGRAM_API}/sendPhoto`,
        {
            headers:{'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
        },{
            body: {
                'chat_id': chatId,
                'caption': caption,
                'photo': './image.jpeg'
            }
        })
    return res.send()
} catch (e) {
    console.log('\nSTATUS RESPONSE: ' + e.response.status)
    console.log('\nMESSAGE RESPONSE: ' + e.response.statusText)
}}
```

but I'm getting this message back: {"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: there is no photo in the request"}

I tried with a web url and it sends normally.

What could I be missing? Do I have to upload the local images in some repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue recently, I managed to solve the problem using [form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) npm package and built-in `fs` module.

```js
const FormData = require('form-data');
const fs = require('fs');

const axiosImage = async(chatId, caption, res) => {
    try {
        const formData = new FormData();
        
        formData.append('chat_id', chatId);
        formData.append('photo', fs.createReadStream('./image.jpeg'));
        formData.append('caption', caption);
    
        const response = await axios.post(`${TELEGRAM_API}/sendPhoto`, formData, {
            headers: formData.getHeaders(),
        });

        return res.send();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked, thanks, I had seen something similar, but I was not able to apply. I will study about. again thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

From the Telegram [api docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files)

> 1. If the file is already stored somewhere on the Telegram servers, you don't need to reupload it: each file object has a file_id field, simply pass this file_id as a parameter instead of uploading. There are no limits for files sent this way.
> 2. Provide Telegram with an HTTP URL for the file to be sent. Telegram will download and send the file. 5 MB max size for photos and 20 MB max for other types of content.
> 3. Post the file using multipart/form-data in the usual way that files are uploaded via the browser. 10 MB max size for photos, 50 MB for other files.

What you want to send is a file via file upload (3.). This is the answer to what you are trying to achieve:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59177066/4668136

Comment: Thank you, I had seen some examples before coming to ask but I was not able to apply. But now it worked